# Combine two columns and make values distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of towns and regions that I want to combine into one list of unique 'places' using an SQL statement.

The table format is `id | town | region`

I need to keep the format as it is now, because I want to allow users to be able to select either a Town or a Region from this list - because some smaller towns or villages may not be in this list - in which case the Region would be selected.

How would I best combine these two fields into one list? Some `example rows` might be -

```
ID | Town    | Region
 1  | Camden  | Greater London
 2  | Bromley | Greater London
```

So I would like both `Camden` and `Greater London` to appear once in this list using a mysql statement. I have tried `union` and `distinct` in various ways, but which is the best method?

Comment: I think you're going to need to make your example list a little longer, because it looks like a _very_ simple SELECT should do the trick.

Comment: Is that example row, the expected result, or the data as it is?

Comment: thats the data as it is, so I basically want a single column of everything

Comment: There are no latitude or longitude columns here. Please delete this ridiculous question

Answer (score 3):

If you want them to show up in a single field, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT town AS place FROM towns
UNION
SELECT region AS place FROM towns;
```

Note, `UNION` has an implied `DISTINCT` effect unless `UNION ALL` is used.
*Also, the second alias is not needed; UNIONs use the identifiers from the first SELECT unioned. I just do that for clarity.*

---

The first SELECT will give you a list of towns like:

```
Camden
Bromley
Bedford
```

The second will give you a list of regions, like:

```
Greater London
Greater London
Lesser London ;)
```

The UNION merges these results and takes the distinct ones, result in:

```
Camden
Bromley
Bedford
Greater London
Lesser London ;)
```

If the results have something more than once, it almost always an illusion from having something like "ABC " and "ABC" in the table; sometimes it is even due to having non-printing characters in the strings (which can be harder to detect and resolve).

Comment: This makes sense, although somehow "Greater London" and every other region seems to be omitted? I almost need something between what UNION and UNION ALL are doing

Comment: @Tim You should post your query and result, because what you are describing doesn't make much sense. There is no middle ground between UNION and UNION ALL, one removes the duplicates and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Tim Are you sure you selected region in the second SELECT?

Comment: Yes basically the towns and regions appear more than once (on different rows) in the table hence the duplication issue

Comment: @Tim were you replying to me? as anything past the "yes" seems irrelevant to what I said.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select distinct town from towns
union
select distinct region from towns
```

Comment: thanks, i've made my question a bit clearer - it's just the one table

Comment: Thanks, just tried your edit -- it seems to give duplicates of the same row though so I have 'Greater London' many times.

Comment: I don't see how the `select distinct region from towns` could give you duplicates. By definition it cannot. Maybe the "town" column has repetitions?

Comment: Ah, yes - it does.. there's different latitude and longitude columns here as well. Is it still possible to achieve?

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: @Tim `distinct` is row wide, not on a particular field; if you're adding additional columns to the SELECT, then the answers to the question you actually asked will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct var1, var2 from test;
```

See linked sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21730/1

Is this what you want?

or

do you want those two columns to be combined into one?

```
select distinct var1 as combined from test union
select distinct var2 as combined from test
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21730/3

Comment: Basically the second answer, although this seems to only contain var1 (town) :(

Comment: Can you post your example on SQL fiddle?